# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android-studio, retrofit, response

```
Using Retrofit Request to get data.  
data is fetched successfully  
 @POST("UIGAttendance/UserRegistration")   
        Call<RegistrationListApi> signUp(@Query("CNIC") String CNIC ,@Query("FullName")  
        String FullName,@Query("address") String address, @Query("Email")
        String Email,@Query("Mobile") StringMobile, @Query("Username") String Username,
        @Query("Password") String Password, @Query("HostName") String HostName);
```

//data I want to get[postman --](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf2Nb.png)

Comment: list ==== 
public class ApprovedUserList {
    @SerializedName("Approved User")
    public List<UserConfirmation> userConfirmations;
}

Comment: model class ==public class UserConfirmation {
    public String ResponseCode;
    public String ResponseDesc;

    public UserConfirmation(String responseCode, String responseDesc) {
        ResponseCode = responseCode;
        ResponseDesc = responseDesc;
    }

    public String getResponseCode() {
        return ResponseCode;
    }

    public String getResponseDesc() {
        return ResponseDesc;
    }
}

Comment: calling ---    new APIRequest().getRequest().signUp(CNIC,FullName, address, Email,  Mobile,Username, Password, HostName)
                        .enqueue(new ResponseCallback<RegistrationListApi>(Registration.this) {
                            @Override
                            public void onData(RegistrationListApi registrationListApi) {
                                String code=registrationListApi.signUpModels.get(0).getResponseCode();
                                String codeText=registrationListApi.signUpModels.get(0).getResponseDesc();